# Try to fix broken install - dictionaries-common

Tags: debian, apt

I am trying to fix a broken install and got this error :

```
➜  Downloads sudo apt --fix-broken install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dictionaries-common
Suggested packages:
  wordlist
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dictionaries-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
19 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/239 kB of archives.
After this operation, 776 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 38166 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dictionaries-common_1.28.4_all.deb ...
Adding 'diversion of /usr/share/dict/words to /usr/share/dict/words.pre-dictiona
ries-common by dictionaries-common'
dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting '/usr/share/dict/words.pre-dicti
onaries-common' with
  different file '/usr/share/dict/words', not allowed
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/dictionaries-common_1.28.
4_all.deb (--unpack):
 new dictionaries-common package pre-installation script subprocess returned err
or exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/dictionaries-common_1.28.4_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Do you know how to fix it ?

OS : Debian 11 - Bullseye